# Is there some code in ggpubr that turns the P value to non-scientific to add to graph

Tags: r, ggpubr

GGPUBR has added the P value onto scatterplot, however I need it to be non scientific.

I have tried the following code but this has not worked.

```
compare_means(formula, data, method = "pearson", paired = FALSE,
group.by = NULL, ref.group = NULL, symnum.args = list(),
p.adjust.method = "holm", ...)



my_data <- read.csv("qPCR.csv")
 library(ggpubr)

 ggscatter(my_data, 
 x = "Intenties"                                                   
 y = "qPCR",
 size = 4,
 color = '#a8329b',
 add = 'reg.line',
 add.params = list(color='black'),
 cor.coef = TRUE,
 cor.coeff.args = list(output.type = 'text', size = 5, 
 color = '#a8329b',   label.sep = "\n"),
 cor.method = "pearson",
 conf.int = TRUE,    
 xlab = "Breath",                                                
 ylab = "qPCR ml/copies log")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p values are not very scientific [1](https://www.amstat.org/asa/files/pdfs/P-ValueStatement.pdf)[ASA statement on p-values], but if you mean you are getting scientific notation, I made up some data and the answer is not in scientific notation. Maybe you just have a very low p-value result.

```
my_data <- data.frame("Intenties" = 1:100, "qPCR" = rnorm(100, 100, 15))

ggscatter(my_data, 
          x = "Intenties",                                                   
          y = "qPCR",
          size = 4,
          color = '#a8329b',
          add = 'reg.line',
          add.params = list(color='black'),
          cor.coef = FALSE,
          # cor.coeff.args = list(output.type = 'text', size = 5, 
          #                       color = '#a8329b',   label.sep = "\n"),
          cor.method = "pearson",
          conf.int = TRUE,    
          xlab = "Breath",                                                
          ylab = "qPCR ml/copies log") + 
  annotate("text", 25, 125, label = "p < 0.1")
```

[image: p value annotated in]

Comment: The statement that p-values are unscientific may be misleading. Please reread the ASA statement. My guess is that `options(scipen)` is set too low.

Comment: Sorry probably not explained myself well.  Its showing on the graph as 8.5e -05 which is significant but what I would like to show instead is <0.001.

Comment: In case you did not notice the edited version, I used the ```annotate()``` layer from ggplot2. ggpubr doesn't give the option you want, but that's because ggpubr is about making ggplot2 publication quality charts without getting into a lot of complicated details.